# How to raise an issue about "sfdx force:apex:test:run --resultformat human"

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

As most Salesforce test runners report a stack trace that points to the failed test line (and usefully the calling lines that is helpful when more complex test classes are used) we generally do not include a failure message in assertions as that would violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) e.g.:

```
System.assertEquals(relationships[3].Id, relatedContacts[2].relationshipSob.Id);
```

Just noticed that:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --classnames WizControllerTest --resultformat human
```

doesn't output the failing line yet alone the stack trace making it hard to understand exactly what failed when multiple similar assertions are present in a test method:

```
TEST NAME                                 OUTCOME  MESSAGE                                                                                               RUNTIME (MS)
────────────────────────────────────────  ───────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────
WizControllerTest..readRecord             Pass                                                                                                           93
WizControllerTest..readRelatedRecords     Fail     "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: a0356000000GohBAAS, Actual: a0356000000Goh9AAC"  382
```

(Yes you can change to `--resultformat json` but then it is not easy to spot the "StackTrace" output.)

If you know of a channel to Salesforce where I can raise this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you could post an Idea? I do remember seeing on here someone mentioning a place where the developers of sfdx are really active so hopefully someone can post on here where that is.

Comment: There is a lot of activity, including the developers, on the [Salesforce DX](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1) group in the success community.

Comment: Thanks both. My experience of posting ideas is that developer ones rarely get any traction. I'll take a look at the Salesforce DX group.

Comment: I would say thats the answer David. Post it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of activity, including the developers, on the [Salesforce DX](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1) group in the success community. The team on the Salesforce side is very responsive and engaged with issue reports and ideas.

Comment: No Salesforce response day 1.